# Not getting response Volley android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

[image] This is my code, I'm using volley to call a web service

```
private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Anything wrong, getting `NullPointerException`

URL:

https://www.bgr.ionidea.com/math_lms/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=840e7d1cb52ca12239b01926310e0c68&wsfunction=local_math_get_android_version&moodlewsrestformat=json

ShowJson method

```
 private void showJSON(String json){
        ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
        pj.parseJSON();
        CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.id,ParseJSON.app_version);
        listView.setAdapter(cl);
    }
```

Parse JSON class

```
public class ParseJSON {

    public static String[] id;
    public static String[] app_version;


    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_APP_VERSION = "app_version";


    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            id = new String[users.length()];
            app_version = new String[users.length()];


            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                id[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
                app_version[i] = jo.getString(KEY_APP_VERSION);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the logcat stacktrace of nullpointer

Comment: And if you can post your URL also..!!

Comment: @SripadRaj  Question edited with lagcat image and url

Comment: create array request

Comment: @SathishKumarJ  Question edited with lagcat image and url

Comment: show your showJSON(response) method

Comment: @jankigadhiya Question edited with lagcat image and url

Comment: @Naveen: show `showJSON ` method code and also line number 64

Comment: The error is at this line `CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.id,ParseJSON.app_version);`. please debug and check..!!

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK showJSON method added in question

Comment: Could you show the ParseJSON class?

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal ParseJSON class added

Comment: @Naveen see my answer below.

Comment: @Ironman It is a integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do something with your JSON.
You first ask for a JSONObject.
In this JSONObject you ask for a JSONArray named result.
In this JSONArray you ask for 2 values: id and app_version.
So I think you JSON needs to look something like this:

```
{
    "result": [
      {"id": "1", "app_version": "1"}
    ]
}
```

With some more users it would look something like:

```
{
  "result": [
      {"id": "1", "app_version": "1"},
      {"id": "2", "app_version": "1"},
      {"id": "3", "app_version": "2"}
    ]
}
```

**OR**

If you can't change the JSON you need to make some changes:

1. Don't use a JSONObject at the start but start immediatly with the JSONArray like `users = new JSONArray(json);`
2. Like @Ironman told you need to change your id to be an int[] instead of a String[] and use `getInt()` instead of `getString()`.

Comment: see my answer you will get the solution. The Actual problem I get it.

Comment: @Ironman I think your solution isn't complete and wouldn't work

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal Yes, am not getting 'result' in the URL what should I do for that and that ID is in integer

Comment: @Ironman It (probably) would not work since he is asking for a JSON object so the JSON should start with { and end with } (which it doesn't) and then he also requests a JSON array in this JSONObject named "result" (which isn't named anywhere in the JSON).

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal Ya. That's right and I found also the Problem. In Json `id` field is `Integer` and In class he declare as `String` see again.

Comment: @Naveen I have added a solution for if you can't change the JSON

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal id field was not problem but JSONArray named result problem, removed  JSON object and worked fine

Comment: @Naveen Glad I could help

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal Thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

I found the Solution your `id` field you are taking in class is `String` and in `response` you will get the `Integer` value. That's why the error is occure.

[image]

**Explantion :**

In your response you get this `"id":1` but actually you require this `"id":"1"`.

**Changing :**

**1.)** change this `public static String[] id;` to `public static Integer[] id;`

**2.)**  change this `id[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);` to `id[i] = jo.getInt(KEY_ID);`.

Comment: in ParseJson class?

Comment: where I have to change

Comment: @Naveen first tell me your `id` is `String` or `Integer` ?

Comment: @Naveen do changing as I suggested in my answer ?

Comment: @Naveen did you get it or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114237/discussion-between-naveen-and-ironman).

Comment: I changed that Json but still not working, check Url

Comment: @Naveen go to discussion in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is here:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "app_version": "1"
  }
]
```

Here , it is a list of json object. Object contains "id" that is integer and "app_version" is String. You can easily parse this response using `Gson` library. Here is sample code:

add this dependency in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Now create a class like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class ResponseObject {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("app_version")
    public String app_version;

}
```

Now, you can parse your response using this way:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ResponseObject>>() {
                    }.getType();
 List<ResponseObject> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Here, `jsonArray` is your response array.

Hope this will help you.